# Why will cout.imbue(locale("")) cause memory leaks?

Tags: c++, memory-leaks, global-variables, locale, iostream

My compiler is Visual VC++ 2013. The following simplest program will cause a few memory leaks.

**Why? How to fix it?**

```
#define _CRTDBG_MAP_ALLOC

#include <stdlib.h>
#include <crtdbg.h>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <locale>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    _CrtSetDbgFlag(_CRTDBG_ALLOC_MEM_DF|_CRTDBG_LEAK_CHECK_DF);

    cout.imbue(locale("")); // If this statement is commented, then OK.
}
```

The debug window outputs as follows:

```
Detected memory leaks!
Dumping objects ->
{387} normal block at 0x004FF8C8, 12 bytes long.
 Data: <z h - C N   > 7A 00 68 00 2D 00 43 00 4E 00 00 00 
{379} normal block at 0x004FF678, 12 bytes long.
 Data: <z h - C N   > 7A 00 68 00 2D 00 43 00 4E 00 00 00 
{352} normal block at 0x004FE6E8, 12 bytes long.
 Data: <z h - C N   > 7A 00 68 00 2D 00 43 00 4E 00 00 00 
{344} normal block at 0x004FE498, 12 bytes long.
 Data: <z h - C N   > 7A 00 68 00 2D 00 43 00 4E 00 00 00 
{318} normal block at 0x004FD5C8, 12 bytes long.
 Data: <z h - C N   > 7A 00 68 00 2D 00 43 00 4E 00 00 00 
{308} normal block at 0x004F8860, 12 bytes long.
 Data: <z h - C N   > 7A 00 68 00 2D 00 43 00 4E 00 00 00 
Object dump complete.
Detected memory leaks!
Dumping objects ->
{387} normal block at 0x004FF8C8, 12 bytes long.
 Data: <z h - C N   > 7A 00 68 00 2D 00 43 00 4E 00 00 00 
{379} normal block at 0x004FF678, 12 bytes long.
 Data: <z h - C N   > 7A 00 68 00 2D 00 43 00 4E 00 00 00 
{352} normal block at 0x004FE6E8, 12 bytes long.
 Data: <z h - C N   > 7A 00 68 00 2D 00 43 00 4E 00 00 00 
{344} normal block at 0x004FE498, 12 bytes long.
 Data: <z h - C N   > 7A 00 68 00 2D 00 43 00 4E 00 00 00 
{318} normal block at 0x004FD5C8, 12 bytes long.
 Data: <z h - C N   > 7A 00 68 00 2D 00 43 00 4E 00 00 00 
{308} normal block at 0x004F8860, 12 bytes long.
 Data: <z h - C N   > 7A 00 68 00 2D 00 43 00 4E 00 00 00 
Object dump complete.
The program '[0x5B44] cpptest.exe' has exited with code 0 (0x0).
```

Comment: The atexit() function runs too early, the CRT didn't cleanup yet.  Use `_CrtSetDbgFlag(_CRTDBG_LEAK_CHECK_DF);` instead.

Comment: The interesting fact is that it's not guaranteed to be called before or after the `cout` destructor: the implementation is allowed to delay the initialization of `cout` until its first usage, and the function registered with `atexit` is run before the destructors of static-duration objects whose initialization is already serialized when `atexit` is called (C++11 §3.6.3 ¶3). Since the first usage of `cout` is after `atexit`, it's not determined if `cout`'s destructor will have already been called when the lambda runs. C++ rules for globals are outright madness.

Comment: @HansPassant, if I use `_CrtSetDbgFlag(_CRTDBG_LEAK_CHECK_DF);`, then `new int;` will not be detected as a memory leak. Why?

Comment: Sorry, use `_CrtSetDbgFlag(_CRTDBG_LEAK_CHECK_DF | _CRTDBG_ALLOC_MEM_DF);`

Comment: @HansPassant, if I use `_CrtSetDbgFlag(_CRTDBG_LEAK_CHECK_DF | _CRTDBG_ALLOC_MEM_DF);` then the original problem comes back.

Comment: Hmm, that works fine on my machine.  Are you sure you removed the atexit() lambda?

Comment: @HansPassant, My real code is `int main() {   _CrtSetDbgFlag(_CRTDBG_ALLOC_MEM_DF|_CRTDBG_LEAK_CHECK_DF);   std::cout.imbue(std::locale(""));} ` the problem is the same.

Comment: There are some one-off memory allocations in the CRT that are never freed. This is a leak, but it never gets worse so it doesn't really matter.

Comment: @AlanStokes, I know it is not a real problem. However, it interferes if I want to detect memory leaks in my my own modules. I cannot tell if the memory leaks are of my own modules or of CRT's modules.

Comment: Please note a related solution that worked for me, from http://stackoverflow.com/a/34962917/368896: In the application destructor, swap out the locale to clear dynamically allocated memory.  From the answer I just linked, the code in the application destructor is `std::locale::global(std::locale("C"));`; perhaps the corresponding fix for this question is, simply, in the application destructor, `cout.imbue(locale("C"));` (I haven't checked specifically but thought I'd point out the solution to the similar problem).

Answer (score 4):

I was using `std::codecvt` and get a similar problem. I am not sure whether it is a same cause. Just try to provide s possible way to discover the root cause.

You can reference the example in http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/locale/codecvt/in/

It actually "use" the member of `mylocale`, and it seems without an r-value reference version overload. So when directly write `const facet_type& myfacet = std::use_facet<facet_type>(std::locale());` may cause the same problem. .

So try

```
auto myloc = locale("");
cout.imbue(myloc);
```